# Android: How to set OnClickListener for Button is ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` in which each item is an xml layout with a (`TextView` and a `Button`).

I haven't used custom **Adapter**. So how do I set an `OnClickListener` for the Button in a particular row?

My aim is to retrieve the complete text String from that particular row when `Button` is clicked for that row.

```
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Deal deal;
```

Note : I have not used custom adapter. I don't how how to use it. I'm new to this.

```
        deal = new Deal();
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);                                           
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.deal_info, R.id.dealinfo, list);
        /*
          What if i have two TextViews in my deal_info.xml...
          what to do in that case?*/
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot_of_deals: dataSnapshot.child("Deals").getChildren()){

                    deal = snapshot_of_deals.getValue(Deal.class);

                    list.add("NAME      : " + deal.getName() +"\n"+
                             "CONTACT   : " + deal.getContact() +"\n"+
                             "ADDRESS   : " + deal.getAddress() +"\n"+
                             "SOW[Date] : " + deal.getReap() +"\n"+
                             "REAP[Date]: " + deal.getSow() +"\n"+
                             "ID of deal: " + deal.getDateid());
                }
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

my row layout (**deal_info.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    ..>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dealinfo"
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dealinfo"
        android:text="Accept" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a Button ? It would be easier to retrieve the text on item click I think...

By the way, if you want to implement a custom adapter, it's not too complicated. [Here is a tutorial to do it](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)

In the given article, you will see a callback named `getView()`. It is where you make the link between row and data. And it is here you have to add an `OnClickListener` to your button.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create custom listview adapter (like baseAdapter)
so you can easily set click on items button , 
but as current now you just used default adapter ,so you can add onItemClickListener on listview.

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //do your stuff
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            String message =textView.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    });
}
```